# Hash struct using an object

Tags: c++, hash

I was given a piece of code to help me on an assignment, but I'm having trouble implementing it in my solution. Here's the piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tr1/unordered_set>

using namespace std;
using std::tr1::unordered_set;


struct ihash
    : std::unary_function<int, std::size_t>
{


    std::size_t operator()(const int& x) const
    {
        return x;
    }
};
```

I have an object that I'd like to use to decide the size of the hashval I'd like to use. I came up with this:

```
/*int myhash(const Play & key, int tableSize){
    int hashval = 0;
    string keysize = key.getoTeam()+key.getdTeam();
    for(int i=0;i<keysize.length(); i++){
        hashval = hashval*5 + keysize[i];
    }
    return hashval;
}*/
```

But I can't find any code examples that use a struct for a hashtable that do something similarly, and the int version is not working with my declaration of my unordered_set. I declare it like so:

```
unordered_set<Play, myhash> PlaySet;
```

Can anyone help me connect the dots?

Update:

New error: main.cpp:38: error: expected unqualified-id before âreturnâ

I ended up with my has being:

```
struct hashbrowns{
    size_t operator()(const Play & a) const
    {
        string keysize = a.getoTeam()+a.getdTeam();
        size_t seed = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<keysize.length(); i++)
            seed = seed*5 + keysize[i];
    }
    return seed;
};
```

Line 38 being, return seed;

Comment: I think this question and answer describes what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17016175/777186 (this assumes C++11, not TR1, though -- is that relevant?)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Please re-read my question if you can, as I ran into a new problem.

Comment: +1 just for the great name for the hash functor =P (`hashbrowns` made me chuckle). Well, ok, the question itself is pretty well presented too. That aside, it looks like you're on the right track for providing a hash-function type to your unordered map, especially with the syntax error woolstar found. Were you able to finally get this to work, or did you need some additional help?

Answer (score 1):

In your updated code, your return needs to be a line higher.  Right now its outside of the `operator()` function.

Comment: +1 on catching that. I *think* that solves the OP's problem unless something else popped up we've not seen yet.