# (c++) can't iterate over a vector in a key hasher function

Tags: c++, hash, iterator

I'm trying to implement [my own hash function for a simple object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key), say a vector of integers :

```
struct Key
{
  std::vector<int> vec;

  bool operator==(const Key &other) const
  { return (vec == other.vec); }

};

struct KeyHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
  {
    using std::size_t;
    std::size_t res = 0;

    std::vector <int>::iterator i;
    for (i = k.vec.begin(); i != k.vec.end(); ++i)
    {/* hash code */}

    return res;
  }
};
```

... but I can't iterate over *k.vec*. The line

```
        for (i = k.vec.begin(); i != k.vec.end(); ++i)
```

is rejected by g++ :

```
'no match for operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>::iterator [...]'
```

What's going on ? This syntax would be ok in another context : where's my error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` needs to be `const_iterator`: `k`, and therefore `k.vec`, is `const` here. (Better still, use `auto`.)

Comment: Remember that auto is a C++ 11 feature, so if you are using an older compiler then const_iterator will be your only option.

Comment: Indeed, *std::vector <int>::const_iterator i;* does the trick, thank you.

Comment: ... or still better *for (auto i = k.vec.begin(); i != k.vec.end(); ++i)* without any other declaration for *i*.

Answer (score 1):

try using const_iterator instead of iterator.
k is const.

```
std::vector <int>::const_iterator i;
```

otherwise you will need to remove the constness...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know *const_iterator*.