# Making a dynamically text-addressable list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

In most scripting languages, objects are typically a collection of items, bound to names within those objects. For example (in Javascript), say if I were to initialize this:

```
colors = {
    Blue:  0x0000FF; //Hex Values
    Green: 0x00FF00;
    Red:   0xFF0000;
}
```

At runtime, if a user typeed in a listed color, I can easily return the corresponding hex value using `colors["given_color"]`.

However, how would I express an even remotely similar mechanic in C++, or other compiled languages for that matter? Creating an `enum` would only have meaning statically, where in a contrived example:

```
public enum colors{
    CYAN     =  0x00FFFF,
    MAGENTA  =  0xFF00FF,
    YELLOW   =  0xFFFF00
}
```

cannot, in any way, be used to look up the corresponding Hex of say `std::cin << givenColor;`

That being said, **what options do I have to convert a `std::string` into a data point, pointer, or function pointer?**

Comment: I'd really like to see an answer, which explicitly covers having the enum and the strings for the enum names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data structure you're looking for is called an [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (or a dictionary or associative array). In C++, there's [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) which is always sorted (generally implemented as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)), and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which is generally faster because it uses a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (but the contents are in arbitrary order).

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> colors = {
    {"blue", 0x0000FF},
    {"green", 0x00FF00},
    {"red", 0xFF0000}
};

std::string key = /* something */;
std::string value = colors[key];
```

In response to the question in the comments: Yes, you can store anything you want in a map. The only restriction is that for `std::unordered_map`, [the key type needs implement a hash function and `operator==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key), and for `std::map`, the key type needs to implement `operator<`. The value type can be anything.

Comment: You might want to store the keys only in upper/lower case and convert all incoming queries to that case, if you want case-insensitivity.

Comment: Can pointers to functions or even classes, for certain special behavior, also be mapped in this way? Is that advisable? In my case, I'm trying to spawn instances of classes, determinate of a given `std::string className`.

Comment: @TERMtm: Anything that can be stored in a variable can be held in a map, including function pointers, and class instances.  Note that `std::string` _is_ a class, exactly like any other class you can write.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> colors =
    {
        {"CYAN", 0x00FFFF},
        {"MAGENTA", 0xFF00FF},
        {"YELLOW", 0xFFFF00},
    };

    unsigned int retrieved_color = colors["CYAN"];
}
```

Now, it bother me a little if you are trying to use C++ as a dynamic language like JavaScript. If you really need to map a string, that you got from somewhere out of your control, maybe you received from the network, or something like that, this is fine. This is the way to go.

But compare this solution to an `enum` if all you need is to be able to use the name `CYAN` inside your code:

```
obj.set_color(CYAN);
```

versus

```
obj.set_color(colors["CYAN"]);
```

The first is resolved at compilation time, and `set_color` receives a literal constant as parameter.

In the second, the literal string `"CYAN"` is used to initialize a temporary object `std::string`, and is then copied to a heap allocated place. Then the hash for this string is calculated (O(N), in the size of the string I believe, Java already had problems by using just a few chars when making a string hash), then there is one memory fetch to get the actual value. At last the temporary `std::string` is deallocated. Then the function `set_color` is called.

Is this extra cost irrelevant to your program? Maybe. But in the end, how many irrelevant extra costs will stack up in your final product?

Comment: note that unordered_map requires c++11. Boost offers similar functionality if you cannot use c++11.

Comment: I used `unordered_map` because OP tagged C++11.

Comment: @Ivella Thanks for the concern, if the user input was as simple as a radio-box I would have definitely done that stuff statically. However, I have to respond to typed user commands, hence requiring `map`. Is that possibly a scenario where `unordered_map` still isn't ideal?

Comment: @TERMtm I would like it better to use C strings as key, with type `const char *`, because the creation of a temporary `std::string` would be always avoided. This is not an issue if your key is always an `std::string`, but oftentimes we need to work with C strings, and if you pass a C string as key, a temporary object is created. But using `const char*` as key is more complicated, because we would have to define the hash function for C strings (it is not provided by the standard C++ library).

Answer (score 3):

combine the efficiency of c++ with the easy debugging of overloaded operator << like this:

```
enum class colors {
    CYAN     =  0x00FFFF,
    MAGENTA  =  0xFF00FF,
    YELLOW   =  0xFFFF00
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, colors c)
{
    switch(c) {
        case colors::CYAN : os << "cyan"; break;
        case colors::MAGENTA : os << "magenta"; break;
        case colors::YELLOW : os << "yellow"; break;
    }
    return os;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(play_colors)
{
    std::vector<colors> v { colors::CYAN, colors::YELLOW, colors::MAGENTA };

    std::copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<colors>(cout, ", "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

expected output (after adding in correct headers):

```
cyan, yellow, magenta,
```

Comment: I don't think hiding the string values inside a method and switch-case is the best style... At the very least you should put the switch-case into a "ToString" function, which you then call from the stream operator (and anywhere else you need the string at), if you for some reason don't want to use a map.