# FInd function in unordered_map with custom classes

Tags: c++, stl, find

I am using std::unordered_map with custom classes as shown below. I have correctly initialised and set up the hasher function. What I want to know is how to use the find function and what will it return? I am confused as the reference doc says that for the unordered_map the value acts as the key.

SO was wondering what the iterator would point to in the case of below find function

```
class xyz {
public:
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;

//Required stuff
.
.
.
}

// Required Stuff
.
.
.

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<class xyz, std::string, KeyHasher> dummy = {
    { {10, 11, 12}, "example"},
    { {2, 3, 21}, "another"}
  };
  std::unordered_map<xyz, std::string, keyHasher>::const_iterator got = dummy.find({2, 3, 21});

  //What will find return here? Is it the pointer to string "another"?

}
```

I have referred the following for basic setup of the custom classes. 
[C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/

Comment: Should be `std::unordered_map<xyz, std::string, KeyHasher>` or `std::unordered_map<class xyz, const char *, KeyHasher>`

Answer (score 0):

Given fixed code such as:

```
std::unordered_map<xyz, std::string, keyHasher>::const_iterator got = dummy.find({2, 3, 21});
```

> What will `find` return here? Is it the pointer to `string` `"another"`?

It's an *iterator* to the matching {key, value} `std::pair`.

- You can check that the `find` found the key with `got != dummy.end()`.
- If-and-only-if found, you can access the value `"another"` using the notation `got->second`, or access the key again as `got->first`.

> confused as the reference doc says that for the unordered_map the value acts as the key.

That's just wrong - the `unordered_map` does ***not*** use the value as the key... it associates the value with the key, such that the value can be looked up using the key as discussed above.

Comment: Thank You. About the second question, I misunderstood the reference doc. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/)  I quote the info from the document " In an unordered_set, the value of an element is at the same time its key, that identifies it uniquely. " This line confused me :) thank you .

Comment: @nightfury: it is a bit of a weird thing to say, and can be misleading given a custom comparison or `operator<` on the `set` element type might effectively make something else the key - such as a subset of the value's state.  Elements are only "uniquely identified" in the sense that if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` they're considered equal for the purposes of the set.  BTW, I recommend using cppreference.com over cplusplus.com - the latter is famously unreliable.