# This hash only works for enumeration types

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, clang, unordered-map

I'm working on a (very) simple class in C++ that has a `unordered_map` member:

```
class SDLFontManager : public CPObject, public FontManagerProtocol {

public:

    SDLFontManager() {};

    // flush the cache when the manager is destroyed
    virtual ~SDLFontManager() { flushFontCache(); };

    // load a font from the cache if it exists, or load it from file and cache it.
    virtual FontProtocol* fontWithTTF(const char* filename) {
        if(_cache.find(filename) != _cache.end()) {
            return _cache[filename];
        }

        SDLFont* font = new SDLFont(filename);
        _cache[filename] = font;
        font->retain();

        return font;
    }

    // flush the font cache
    virtual void
    flushFontCache() {
        for(auto font: _cache) {
            font.second->release();
        }
    }

private:

    std::unordered_map<std::string, SDLFont*> _cache;
};
```

When I compile, I get no errors in the class's source, but clang fails, pointing me to the C++ standard library's `functional` file, with the following message:

`functional:2441:5: Static_assert failed "This hash only works for enumeration types"`

[image: stack trace from Clang]

I assume that there is a problem with the hashing function needed for `unordered_map` (which, if I am correct, is implemented as a HashMap). When I replace it with a simple `map`, everything compiles properly. I have other `unordered_map`s in my codebase with `std::string` as keys that compile perfectly.

Is there some obvious mistake I've not spotted? I'm highly doubt this would be a standard library bug.

(if it can be of any help, the code is compiled with `clang-700.0.65` (`Apple LLVM version 7.0.0`, shipped with Xcode 7), no exceptions/RTTI, and `std=c++14`)

**edit**

As pointed out by @dau_sama's answer, `<string>` wasn't included directly (only by including another header), which was causing the problem. The possible duplicate is relatively different, as `std::string` is not a custom class and the standard library provides a hash function for it.

Comment: did you include the string header in this compilation unit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ unordered\_map using a custom class type as the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

Comment: It's included "by proxy" (in an included header file). Could that be the problem?

Comment: It was indeed the problem, including `<string>` explicitly makes the file compile. Is there a way to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: @cesarparent nope, I just added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the string header

```
#include <string>
```

should solve your problem