# What's wrong with my hash key type and function?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I'm trying to write my own hash function for a class that is essentially a wrapper for an unsigned integer. I've been trying to follow this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key): and this resource [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). Why doesn't this work? See code comment for errors.

```
struct Entity
{
    unsigned int id;

    bool operator==( const Entity &other ) const
    {
        return ( id == other.id );
    }
};

template<struct T>
class EntityHash;

template<>
class EntityHash<Entity> // Error: Type name is not allowed
{
public:
    std::size_t operator()( const Entity& entity ) const
    {
        size_t h1 = std::hash<unsigned int>()( entity.id );
        return h1; // Also... do I need a << 1 at the end of this to bitshift even though I'm not combining?
    }
};

// Elsewhere
std::unordered_map<Entity, unsigned int, EntityHash> map; // Error: Argument list for class template EntityHash is missing
```

Comment: About the `<< 1` thing: If you need it depends on your requirements. The code is correct in both cases (well, that part)

Comment: @deviantfan Thanks, I figured since I wasn't combining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <struct T>
class EntityHash;
```

is probably not what you want.  Use `template <class T>` or `template <typename T>`.

The third template argument of `unordered_map` must be a type, not the name of a template.  So:

```
std::unordered_map<Entity, unsigned int, EntityHash<Entity>> map;
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like those errors are gone now. However, the compiler is still complaining "The C++ standard doesn't provide a hash for this type." I don't see how that's possible given I'm specifying the third parameter. Does my operator() overload look okay? Just trying to think what else it could be. EDIT: Nevermind, forgot to make the same changes to a different class elsewhere.