# unordered_map with custom key compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have a question regarding the `std::unordered_map` and a custom class as it's key.
I think some background is required first:

The custom class is a variant data type, which implements basic numerical types and the `std::string` class.
Recently a bro of mine told me that it would be nice if the class supported arrays and hashtables. "Say no more" I thought and started implementing the array functionality (using `std::vector`) which works really great and then I implemented the hashmap functionality (using `unordered_map<Variant, Variant>`).

If I understand it right the hash function (or `operator()` respectively) for the `unordered_map` has to comply to the signature `size_t (*) (const Key_Type &k) const;` which my specialized version of the `std::hash<Variant>` object should do, shouldn't it?
In addition the `unordered_map` needs to check `Key_Type` for equality, which should be possible via `operator==()`, am I correct?

Anyway I'm getting a load of beautiful compiler errors of which this is, in my opinion, the most helpful:
`/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:85:33: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<Variant>) (const Variant&)’`

I really don't understand what's going on and would be really grateful for any insights in what's going on.

Below is a stripped down header of the class `Variant`, I hope enough information is included (to be honest I fear it's too much information but I was not sure what could be omitted).
But I left out most of the implementation details since the problem seems to occur only in the specialized hash object.

Well this is the stripped down version of the `Variant` header:

```
class Variant
{
    private:
        enum Type {NONE = 0, LONG, DOUBLE, STRING, ARRAY, HASH_MAP};
        using Var = struct Var
        {
            union
            {
                int64_t l;
                double d;
                std::string *s;
                std::vector<Variant> *v;
                std::unordered_map<Variant, Variant> *h;
            };
            Type type = NONE;
        };

    public:
        //constructors, destructor and clear function
        Variant() : var() {}
        Variant(long val): Variant(){var.type = LONG; var.l = val;}
        Variant(double val) : Variant(){var.type = DOUBLE; var.d = val;}
        Variant(const std::string &val) : Variant(){var.type = STRING; var.s = new std::string(val);}
        template<typename T, typename... Args>Variant(T val, Args... args) : Variant() {set(val, args...);} //constructs an array

        Variant(const Variant &val); //calls default constructor as well
        Variant(Variant &&val) : Variant() {swap(*this, val);}

        ~Variant(){clear();}
        void clear();

        //set functions
        template<typename T, typename... Args> void set(const T val, Args... args){if(var.type == ARRAY)var.v->clear();add(val, args...);}
        void set(long val);
        void set(double val);
        void set(const std::string &val);
        void set(const Variant &val);

        //add functions
        template<typename T> void add(const T val){add(Variant(val));}
        template<typename T, typename... Args> void add(const T val, Args... args){add(Variant(val)); add(args...);}
        void add(const std::string &val){add(Variant(val));}
        void add(const Variant &val);

        //array access and evaluation functions
        Variant& operator[](const Variant &idx);
        size_t size() const {if(var.type == ARRAY)return var.v->size(); return 0;}
        std::unordered_map<Variant, Variant>::iterator begin(){if(var.type == HASH_MAP)return var.h->begin(); throw Exception("The internal type does not support iterators");}

        //operator= definitions
        template<typename T> Variant& operator=(const T val){set(val); return *this;}
        Variant& operator=(const std::string &val){set(val); return *this;}
        Variant& operator=(Variant val){swap(*this, val); return *this;}

        //operator definitions
        Variant& operator+=(const Variant &right);
        //and operator-=, ^= etc etc...

        //friend definitions (mainly comparison operators)
        friend void swap(Variant &left, Variant &right); //simple swap function
        friend bool operator==(const Variant &left, const Variant &right);
        friend bool operator!=(const Variant &left, const Variant &right);    
        friend std::hash<Variant>;

    private:
        Var var;
};


template <typename T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T &v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<Variant>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Variant &x) const
        {
            if(x.var.type == Variant::DOUBLE)
                return std::hash<double>()(x.var.d);
            else if(x.var.type == Variant::LONG)
                return std::hash<int64_t>()(x.var.l);
            else if(x.var.type == Variant::STRING)
                return std::hash<std::string>()(*x.var.s);
            else if(x.var.type == Variant::ARRAY)
            {
                size_t seed = 0;
                for(size_t i = 0; i < x.var.v->size(); ++i)
                    hash_combine(seed, x.var.v->operator[](i));
                return seed;
            }
            else if(x.var.type == Variant::HASH_MAP)
            {
                size_t seed = 0;
                for(auto it = x.var.h->begin(); it != x.var.h->end(); ++it)
                {
                    hash_combine(seed, it->first);
                    hash_combine(seed, it->second);
                }
                return seed;
            }
            else if(x.var.type == Variant::NONE)
                return 0;
            else
                throw std::runtime_error("This Variant cannot be hashed");
        }
    };
}

inline void swap(Variant &left, Variant &right){Variant::Var tmp(left.var); left.var = right.var; right.var = tmp;}

bool operator==(const Variant &left, const Variant &right);
bool operator!=(const Variant &left, const Variant &right);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Comment: Did you try moving all the specialized `std::` extension *declarations* to above the declaration of the variant class?

Comment: Make your `hash_combine` a struct instead: `struct VariantHasher { size_t operator()(...) { return 0; } };` and pass it to the third template parameter like so: `std::unordered_map<Variant, Variant, VariantHasher>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you use `unordered_map<Variant, Variant>` inside the definition of `Variant` itself. At this point your `hash` specialization is not available yet, that's why the compiler produces the error. You cannot just move hash definition before `Variant` definition because the hash needs access to `Variant` members. What you can do, is to separate declaration and definition of your `hash`:

```
class Variant;

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<Variant>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Variant & x) const;
    };
}

class Variant {
/* Variant definition goes here ... */
};

template <typename T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T &v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}

size_t std::hash<Variant>::operator()(const Variant &x) const
{
    /* hash function implementation here ... */
}
```

But then you have another problem: inside Variant class definition the `Variant` itself is incomplete type. In your union you store only pointers to vector and unordered_map, this is OK, but the begin method (actually, specification of its return type already) requires an instantiation of the `unordered_map<Variant, Variant>` which is not possible at that place.

(Note: [Limited support for containers of incomplete types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4371.html) (only vector, list, and forward_list) will be added to C++17)

To solve this second problem, you can have a `map` member function instead of `begin` function which gives access to the internal map:

```
std::unordered_map<Variant, Variant> & map()
{
    if (var.type == HASH_MAP)
        return *var.h; 
    throw Exception("The internal type does not support iterators");
}
```

Then instead of

```
Variant v;
v.begin();
```

you would use

```
v.map().begin();
```

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't think that my class would suffer from a chicken-egg-problem. Your suggestions fixed the problem, many thanks!

Comment: There's no need to overload `std::hash`.  Instead, place your hashing function in a simple struct and pass it as a template parameter as so: `std::unordered_map<Variant, Variant, VariantHashingStructWithFunctionCallOperatorOverloaded>`