# Custom class pointer as unordered map key

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement unordered_map with pointer to custom class as key and integer as value. 
I thought pointer is just an address, so I wouldn't have to create comparison template for unordered_map, since map would compare between addresses. But I get compile error. 

My code is as follow for simple testing. Can anyone help me to fix what have I done wrong?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(int id){m_id = id;};
        void PrintThis(){cout << " This is test " << endl;};
        int m_id;
};


class Test{
    public:
        unordered_map<MyClass* mc, int test> mapTest;

};

int main(){
    MyClass* mc1 = new MyClass(1);
    MyClass* mc2 = new MyClass(2);

    Test* tt1 = new Test();
    tt1->mapTest.insert(make_pair<MyClass*, int>(mc1, 10));
    tt1->mapTest.insert(make_pair<MyClass*, int>(mc2, 20));

    auto search = tt1->find(mc1);
    if(search != tt1->end()) {
        search->first->PrintThis();
    }else{
        cout << "not Found " << endl;
    }

}
```

Error message is as follow

```
./main.cpp:17:44: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 5)
         unordered_map<MyClass* mc, int test> mapTest;
                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/unordered_map:48:0,
                 from ./main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:97:11: error: provided for 'template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc> class std::unordered_map'
     class unordered_map : __check_copy_constructible<_Alloc>
           ^
./main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
./main.cpp:26:18: error: request for member 'insert' in 'tt1->Test::mapTest', which is of non-class type 'int'
     tt1->mapTest.insert(make_pair<MyClass*, int>(mc1, 10));
```

I think I can manage line 26 error, if line 17 gets fixed...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post the error message. I would say that the error message is quite relevant to your question, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/1865694

Comment: @AlexZywicki The key here is a pointer to the class, and pointers are already hashable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried your code and found 3 problems:

1. Declaration of map: it should read `std::unordered_map<MyClass*, int>`
2. call of undefined functions (`tt1->find`/`tt1->end`, should read `tt1->testMap.XXX`)
3. Call of `make_pair` doesn't require template arguments. The compiler will infer them. This actually causes a problem, as the compiler tries to call `make_pair(MyClass *&&, int &&)`. If I omit the template arguments, it works (`make_pair(mc1, 10)`)

As for point 3:

make_pair is declared as follows in C++11 (C++14 just adds `constexpr`) [(cppreference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair):

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

For template argument deduction, the follwing rule applies (cf. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction))

> 4) If **P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter** (so-called "forwarding reference"), and the corresponding function call **argument is an lvalue**, the type **lvalue reference to A** is used in place of A for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of std::forward)

(emphasis mine)

So the compiler will infer:

```
std::make_pair<MyClass *&, int>(MyClass *&, int &&);
```

where `MyClass *&` can bind to your actual argument.

If you directly specify the template types, the compiler will stick to

```
std::make_pair<MyClass *, int>(MyClass *&&, int &&).
```

As your argument is a lvalue, it cannot be converted to a rvalue-reference, and compilation fails

Comment: Thanks a lot! for 1, I modified as suggestion. For 2, was a mistake.  tt1->mapTest.find(mc1) is the correct one. For 3, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of `unordered_map<MyClass* mc, int test> mapTest;` is invalid syntax. It should be `unordered_map<MyClass*, int> mapTest`.

Also remove the template parameters from your `make_pair` calls and change `tt1->find` to `ttl->mapTest.find()` and `ttl->end()` to `ttl->mapTest.end()`.

Comment: He is also attempting to access the `std::unordered_map<>` instance through his class variable instead of through the actual member variable.