# unordered_set of unordered_map fails on missing hash for type

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map, unordered-set

I have the following nested data structure:

```
map<string, unordered_set<unordered_map<string, string> > > complicateMap;
```

Meaning, a map from string, to a set of maps from string to string.

When trying to compile, I'm getting:

> error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

Narrowing it down, I see that the problem is `unordered_set<unordered_map<...> >`

Seems like `unordered_map`, by itself, doesn't have a default hash.

Is there a better approach to this data structure? Or how to implement a hash for an entire map efficiently?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key as it may answer your question

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Better in terms of what (easier to write, faster, ...)? Efficiency also depends on the stored `unordered_map<string, string>`s; what kind of data are you storing?

Comment: There is a hash for string but not for unordered_map<string, string>, not sure why there would be either! You might want to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: I back @paulm on this one. Adding an element to one of these `unordered_map`s could lead you having duplicate maps. And IMHO come up with a hash for such a map wouldn't be ideal performance wise.

Comment: You are right of course that this is bad practice. But given that, the best solution I could find was to serialize the inner `map` and deserialize it when needed. If anyone wants, I'll post the code.