# Finding Key in std::unordered_map with custom key

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm currently creating a custom std::unordered_map declaration with my custom key:

```
class BASE_DLLSPEC ClientKey
{
  private:
    // this is always true initially until we call SetClientId
    bool emptyId;

    // both of these are guaranteed to be unique
    QString m_connectId; // ip:port format
    QString m_clientId;  // {Uuid} format
    // ----------

  public:
    ClientKey(const QString& connectId = "", const QString& clientId = "") :
      emptyId(true), m_connectId(connectId), m_clientId(clientId)
    { }

    void SetClientId(const QString& clientId)
    {
      m_clientId = clientId;
      emptyId    = false;
    }

    const QString& GetConnectId() const { return m_connectId; }
    const QString& GetClientId() const { return m_clientId; }

    bool operator==(const ClientKey& other) const
    {
      int comp1 = QString::compare(m_connectId, other.GetConnectId());
      int comp2 = QString::compare(m_clientId, other.GetClientId());

      return (comp1 == 0) ||
             (!emptyId && comp2 == 0);
    }
};

struct BASE_DLLSPEC ClientKeyHash
{
  std::size_t operator()(const ClientKey& key) const
  {
    std::string connectId = key.GetConnectId().toStdString();
    std::string clientId  = key.GetClientId().toStdString();

    std::size_t h1 = std::hash<std::string>()(connectId);
    std::size_t h2 = std::hash<std::string>()(clientId);
    return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
  }
};

struct BASE_DLLSPEC ClientKeyEqual
{
  bool operator()(const ClientKey& lhs, const ClientKey& rhs) const
  {
    return lhs == rhs;
  }
};

typedef std::unordered_map<ClientKey,
                           ClientPtr,
                           ClientKeyHash,
                           ClientKeyEqual> ClientMap;
```

I'm having difficulties finding a particular key during my iteration. For some reason my client object is never located when I pass in a key for lookup.

```
ClientKey key = Manager::ClientKey(connectId);
ClientManager& clientManager = Manager::ClientManager::GetInstance();
ClientMap::const_iterator clientIter = clientManager.GetClients().find(key);
```

Even if the key has already been inserted, clientIter is always pointing to the end iterator position. Do you think this is related to having to re-create these ClientKey values on the stack and then passing them into the map for look-up, or do I have a problem elsewhere? Thank you for the clarification and insight.

Comment: I don't see you implementing a hash function for your client key and that's most likely the problem. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Comment: It looks like you allow keys that compare equal to have different hashes. This cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, some considerations to the emptyId field (do not consider invalid formats - which, by the way, is not checked by you either):

```cpp
ClientKey k0("hello", "world");
ClientKey k1("hello");
k1.SetClientId("world");
```

Is there any particular reason that the emtpyId flag should be different for k0 and k1? I personally would say:

1. The flag is implemented incorrectly.
2. It is redundant, you get the same information via `m_clientId.empty()`.

Now the reason for failure:

Consider again `k0` and `k1`, but without SetClientId having been called on k1:

```cpp
ClientKey k0("hello", "world");
ClientKey k1("hello");
```

Imagine `k0` has been inserted in the map, and with `k1` you try to find it. What will happen? k1 produces another hash key than k0, and the map will look at a different bucket than where k0 resides at - and will not find anything.

What I think you want to achieve is having several clients for the same connection id and being able to iterate over these for a given connection id. So you might prefer [`std::unordered_multimap<std::string, ClientPtr>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) (where the string parameter represents the connection id). You will get all clients for a given connection id via [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/equal_range) then, and your class `ClientKey` gets obsolete.

Comment: That is indeed the reason I was encountering this problem. Thank you very much. I initially pass in just the connectId with an empty clientId where I do the find. Followed by if it's a new client setting the clientId. So on re-iteration the clientId is always empty, and in it's current state the hash will utilize the clientId as well on the find.

Answer (score 0):

Your code allows that the following will return true:

```
ClientKey k1("hello", "world");
ClientKey k2("hello", "");
return k1 == k2;
```

However, your hash is based on the combination of connectId and clientId.

`unordered_map::find` does not do an exhaustive search of the map, instead it looks in the bucket for the given hash and compares *just* the entries in the bucket.

You are generating your test key with just `connectId`, so it is looking in the bucket for `ClientKey(connectId, "")` rather than the bucket for `ClientKey(connectId, someOtherValue)`.

You should consider making the hash based exclusively on `connectId`.

Lastly, note your constructor:

```
ClientKey(const QString& connectId = "", const QString& clientId = "") :
  emptyId(true), m_connectId(connectId), m_clientId(clientId)
{ }
```

If I write:

```
ClientKey ck("hello");
```

should `emptyId` really be true?