# Unordered container with multiple keys / values

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

I need a data container for collecting numeric data based on one or multiple keys (like a key built of `int` and `std::string`).

For one key, I simply can use `unordered_map<std::string, int>` respectively `unordered_map<std::string, List<int>>` if multiple values should be collected.

What about having multiple keys? Other posts suggested me to use `std::make_pair<type1, type2>` as key, but this only works for 2 keys and looks a little hacky.

Is there any easy-to-use data structure or library allowing keys built of multiple variables and multiple values assigned to it? The values only must be accessible by the keys (I do not need something like boost::multi_index which provides several interfaces to access values). Furthermore the values must not be sorted in the container, however fast access is desired as the values are added/incremented during data processing.

Comment: Eventually use a `std::tuple` for more than one key value? I don't know if this would be possible.

Comment: Creating a struct with the multiple members and using it as a key will work just fine as long as the needed operator(s) are overloaded.

Comment: @GillBates I think in case of unordered collections apart from equality operator std::hash should also be specialized...

Comment: Stupid question (or not): "multiple" in sense "composite key", or "multiple" in sense "any of multiple keys point one data"

Comment: @W.F. Very sp00ky indeed.

Comment: @JacekCz Multiple in sense of a "composite key". Like a primary key in a DB built of multiple fields.

Comment: @GillBates I used a struct but I receive an error, is it possible that I have to implement a hash function? How could it look like for the struct consisting of a std::string and int value?

Comment: @Patrick because You write "based on one or multiple keys ". Sorry for time waste

Comment: @Patrick http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/1870760 shows you everything you need to know, just combine the two members with `std::hash`.

Comment: @Patrick here's comes a problem... I'm not sure if one even can specialize `std::hash` to types that are built-in or implemented in `std::` namespace without risk of undefined behaviour...

Comment: @W.F. Yes you can, easily, check the link.

Comment: @GillBates well I'm not saying that you can't I'm saying that it may cause UB as long as you are specializing for built-in type or the type from `std::` namespace...

Comment: @W.F. There is absolutely no risk. I don't get why you would think that.

Comment: @GillBates http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124271/discussion-between-gill-bates-and-w-f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::tuple for the same. Tuple Comparison works for multiple elements of almost all built in types. for example

```
typedef tuple<int, int> tx;
tx t1 = make_tuple(1, 1);
tx t2 = make_tuple(1, 2);

if (t1 == t2) {
        cout << "EQUAL" << endl;
}
```

or

```
typedef tuple<string, string> tx;
    tx t1 = make_tuple("AB", "CD");
    tx t2 = make_tuple("AB", "CD");

    if (t1 == t2) {
        cout << "EQUAL" << endl;
    }
```

Use the tuple as the key in you unordered_map

An example of using map could be

```
map<tx, int> mp;
mp[make_tuple("AB", "CD")] = 100;
mp[make_tuple("EF", "GH")] = 200;
```

To Update an existing Key, we can use

```
mp[t1] = 300;
```

Comment: I tried it with tuple<std::string, int> and it requires to implement a hash function. So basically the same effort is required as by using a struct instead?

Comment: No You dont, you can write a map like this.

Comment: typedef tuple<string, string> tx;
 tx t1 = make_tuple("AB", "CD");
 tx t2 = make_tuple("AB", "CD");

 if (t1 == t2) {
  cout << "EQUAL" << endl;
 }

 map<tx, int> mp;
 mp[make_tuple("AB", "CD")] = 100;
 mp[make_tuple("EF", "GH")] = 200;

 mp[t1] = 300;

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation! I think that tuples have the advantage of not having to implement any hash and comparison function, but if many parameters are used, structs are more comprehensible.