# How to use std::vector as the type of key for an std::unordered_map in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, hash, unordered-map

I'm trying to build an `unordered map` to contain points in n-dimensional
   space. I understand that `std::vector` meets all the requirements for being a key in `std::map`, and yet this code does not compile. I get a long list of error messages, but this seems the most problematic:

> `error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<std::vector<int> >) (const std::vector<int>&)'.`

Does anyone have any idea as to why g++ doesn't seem to think that `std::vector<int>` is hashable?

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> point;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<point, int>jugSpace;
    vector<int> origin(3, 0);

    jugSpace.insert( pair<point,int>(origin, 0) );
}
```

Comment: i'd make the key a pointer to the vector...

Comment: @user2717954, terrible idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ unordered\_map using a custom class type as the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

Comment: This doesn't directly relate to the question, but using `vector<int>` as a `point` seems unnecessarily expensive. Sensible uses of points all traffic in points with the same number of dimensions, so the variable size of a `vector`, and the resultant overhead, is generally not needed. I'd go with a `struct` with appropriate data members, or possible a template that takes the number of dimensions as a template argument and uses `std::array` internally. Of course, with either of these approaches you still have to make the point type hashable.

Comment: @SauravSahu I thought, being that vector<int> is a fairly common class, there would already be some support for hashing it in either the STL or Boost, an issue I don't think was covered in that question. Is it the case that there is not?

Comment: @PeteBecker I thought that std::array and std::vector were equally expensive for similar operations, and I can avoid templates using vectors, hence the decision.

Comment: `std::vector` is resizable, so it allocates from the free store and reallocates as necessary. `std::array` is fixed size, and doesn't do any separate allocations.

Comment: @MontyEvans: Chances are that you won't notice a performance difference. What's more important is that a vector is semantically incorrect for the task. A point is not something where you can simply add or remove elements or where the size is not known before the program runs, i.e. you don't know if something's a 2D point or a 3D point. A vector can also become empty. What's an empty point? A vector just doesn't make much sense to represent a point. `std::array` makes sense. In C++, good performance follows good semantics much more easily than the other way round.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Right, I see how that makes sense. The problem here is that I don't know the size of the point-container at compile time - I want to be able to work in a given number of dimensions, and I understand that using std::array requires a size declaration at compile time?

Comment: @MontyEvans: You may find a template useful. It would still be compile time, then, but flexibly so. If you really know the size only at run-time and it could be anything from 1 to n, then there's hardly a way around `std::vector`, though. You should, however, still wrap it in a class of your own, so as to limit `std::vector`'s interface to what you need from it, and gain the freedom to change or optimise the implementation later on.

Answer (score 7):

Unordered map requires availability of hash function for the key. Such function does not exist for `std::vector` in standard implementation.

You could use `std::map`, though - it requires comparison operator, which exists for vector.

If you really must use vector as a key to hash map (which seems dubious), you should implement hashing function yourself.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp, So you may use it in `std::map`.

Comment: > You could use std::map, though - it requires comparison operator, which exists for vector

You should point out that doing this might not lead to the same performance

Answer (score 5):

You need to specialize template class `std::hash<>` for your point like:

```
namespace std {
  template<>
  class hash<point> {
  public:
    size_t operator()(const point &p) const {
      // put here your hash calculation code
    }  
  };
}
```

Or create custom hasher class and specify its type as template member for `std::unordered_map`:

```
class my_hash {
public:
  size_t operator()(const point &p) const {
    // your hash calculation code
  }
};

// somewhere in your code, where you declare your unordered_map variable
std::unordered_map<point, int, my_hash> myUnorderedMap;
```

If you want to use `boost::hash_value` as hash function then just return its result in your hasher implementation, ex:

```
class my_hash {
public:
  size_t operator()(const point &p) const {
    return boost::hash_value(p);
  }
};
```

Comment: I can't be the first person to have needed a hash function for a vector though? I don't really understand the documentation, but it looks like boost defines that hash already in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html.

Comment: @MontyEvans, I think you can return value of `boost::hash_value(p);` from any of hash functions

Comment: Ah, okay, so just including the header file from boost won't do it for me, I need to write a hash function and then return the value as given by boost?

Comment: @MontyEvans, that's right. I've just updated my post for you.

Comment: Thanks a million! I've downloaded boost and it's all working now.