# How does `unordered_set` implement `find` in O(1) time?

Tags: c++, data-structures, time

The C++ [documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/) states that the `find` operation has an average-case time complexity of Θ(1), and a worst-case complexity of O(n), where n is the size of the set. The worst-case bound makes sense. I don't see why the average-case bound does. I'm not too familiar with average-case complexity, but naively, I would expect the argument of `find` to be uniformly distributed over the set, so that searching for it linearly would yield an expected time of n/2, for an average time of Θ(n/2) = Θ(n).

I tried looking this up on various documentation websites (GeeksForGeeks, etc.) to no avail. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487673/time-complexity-of-unordered-setint-find-method) question is similar, but only asks *what* the complexity of `find` operation is, not *why* it is what it is.

Apparently, `unordered_set` is implemented using buckets and hash maps. I'm not very familiar with these; perhaps they hold the key.

Comment: Because it calculates a hash value that can in constant time be converted to one lookup (only in the cases of hash value collissions will the lookup be slower). Read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Also not O(1) doesn't mean it needs to be fast. The calculation of the hash value takes some time (overhead).

Comment: I would vote [this question](/questions/8162501/worse-case-time-complexity-put-get-hashmap) as a duplicate, but it talks about Java (same data structure and approach as `unordered_set` though)

Comment: Additionally: unordered sets (and maps) operate on an internal *array*; the case might arise that this array gets to small to retain the maximum load factor; in that case it needs to be increased, requiring to copy all the elements contained (-> O(n)).

Comment: _I tried looking this up on various documentation websites (GeeksForGeeks, etc.)_ G4G is NOT a reliable or useful website. Avoid it like the plague. Use cppreference or other reputable sources.

Comment: Up to date sources to learn more about C++ are : a recent [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), or online [learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/), for reference material (like explanations about containers like std::string, std::vector, std::string_view) have a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and finally to keep up to date on the latest C++ coding guidelines use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). Stay away from geekforgeeks and competitive coding

Comment: btw this isnt "the c++ documentation". I don't know if it has improved in the meanwhile, because I have been staying away for too long from cplusplus.com. When I did use it, it had too much incomplete, wrong, and partly confusing entries. I can recommend this https://cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/ (which isnt "official documentation" either, but it is community curated and usually rather close to the wording in the standard). And GeeksforGeeks is not a "documentation" at all.

Comment: The worst-case is when there are O(`size()`) collisions for `key`, and it has to walk the bucket

Comment: "I'm not very familiar with these; perhaps they hold the key." They do. Start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 2):

Very informal explanation:

A hash table does not search through all the elements when you look something up.

The table is an array of "buckets" (usually lists).

Hashing (which is assumed to take constant time) produces a number, from that number you derive (in constant time) an array index, and array indexing takes constant time.

Finding the correct element inside the bucket is linear in the size of the bucket, but with few enough collisions it is constant on average.
Thus, the time complexity is constant on average (in the size of the table).

The worst case occurs when all elements are in the same bucket, since that *does* involve a linear search through all the elements..