# std::unordered_map Error in declaration

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

In `Execution.cpp`, I need to add `unordered_map`. I used the following instruction:

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<StringRef, std::unordered_map<StringRef, struct IntRel>> BinaryRel;
```

but it invokes the following errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: error: declaration of ‘struct std::hash<llvm::StringRef>’
    struct hash;

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1082:53: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::hash<llvm::StringRef>’
    using __ebo_h1 = _Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, _H1>;
```

Comment: You forgot to define a hash function for StringRef, or perhaps #include an existing definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ unordered\_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specialize `std::hash` for your `StringRef` type. For example:

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct StringRef {};
struct IntRel {};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<StringRef>
    {
      std::size_t operator()(const StringRef& s) const noexcept { return 0; }  
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<StringRef, std::unordered_map<StringRef, struct IntRel>> BinaryRel;

}
```

Although I suggest better implementation of hashing function :D For this you can use one of existing specializations (`std::hash<std::string>` ? if your `StringRef` possibly contains `std::string` object).