# Unordered_map with custom class as a key

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

My question is how to use a custom class as a key. I have found a few links for what I need to do such as create a custom hash function on my class, as well as change both () and == (I believe). The problem is that I cannot comment on those threads and I am lost as to how to implement these 3 things in a .h file. 
[C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)
this website just about sums up the problem but I cannot ask how or where to put my information to customize it to my code. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Edit: 
my class code:

```
class apples{
public:
    apples(){
        removed = false;
        hasPortal = false;
        distance = 9999;
        from.first = -1;
        from.second = -1;
        location.first=-1;
        location.second=-1;
        portal.first = -1;
        portal.second = -1;
    }
    bool removed,hasPortal;
    int distance;
    pair<int,int> from;
    pair<int, int> location;
    pair<int,int> portal;
    int portalDistance;
};
```

then I set up the minPriorityQueue for Dijkstra's

```
//Dijkstra's Algorithm
//1. Put all nodes (apples) into the queue with high distance all except the begining apple
//2. pop out and update all distances from distance + distanace to neighboring apple
//3. continuously pop out and update the neighboring apples of the popped apple
MinPriorityQueue<apples> tree;
for(int i=0; i<m.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<m[i].size(); j++){
        if(!fruits[i][j].removed){
            tree.push(fruits[i][j], fruits[i][j].distance);
        }
    }
}
```

my minPriorityQueue:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility> // Has pair and swap

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MinPriorityQueue
{
public:
//Here there is push, pop, decrease_key, and front
//They all work as was tested somewhere else
private:
    unordered_map<T, int> I; // Maps elements to indices in H.
    vector< pair<T, int> > H;     // The array containing the heap.
};
```

So the problem comes when trying to use the custom class as a key. I only vaguely understand the answer for the other question in the link. I guess I am asking for clarification and just understanding where the stuff is supposed to go and how to go about writing the code.

Comment: If your code isn't working and you need help, post a [MCVE]. As is, this question doesn't make any sense; the answers on the question you linked already provide example code.

Comment: Now where's my "it's a duplicate" gone ?  Linked post in the question is a exact dupe and the answer is worked through.

Comment: @user4581301 No problem - SO says I have flagged so I can't flag again.

Comment: Back to the question. Your linked question is a worked example, so we need to see the exact problem(s) you have. Please post a [mcve] or as much as you have done so far.

Comment: I edited the question as was asked!