# std::pair of strings as custom key of unordered_map defined in std fails with template errors

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, compare, stdmap

I have a map defined and used like this

```
// def.h
struct X{};
struct Y{};
struct myStruct
{
   X x;
   Y y;
};

typedef std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, myStruct> myMap;
namespace std
{
   template<> struct pair<std::string, std::string>
   {
      std::string s1,s2;
      pair(const std::string& a, const std::string& b):s1(a),s2(b){}
      bool operator < (const pair<std::string,std::string>& r)
      {
         return (0 < r.s1.compare(s1) && (0 < r.s2.compare(s2)));
      }
   };
} 

//use.cpp
class CUse
{
  myMap m;
public:
   CUse():m(0){}
};
```

Some errors emitted by the compiler are extracted as below

1. At the constructor `CUse` initialization,

> note: see reference to function template instantiation
>   'std::unordered_map,myStruct,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator>>::unordered_map(unsigned __int64)' being compiled

2. At the declaration of `m` in CUse

> note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::unordered_map,myStruct,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator>>' being compiled

Comment: What is `m(0)` supposed to do?

Comment: unordered_map key requires a hash and an equality test.

Comment: The first problem is that unordered_map is a hash table, and so requires a hasher for the key. `std::pair` doesn't have one. Then adding your own specializations to namespace std is a big no-no, except in a few very regulated cases. This is not one of those.

Comment: What's your reasoning behind providing a specialization of `pair<std::string, std::string>`? Putting your own types in `namespace std` is a no-no. The root of the problem is that `unordered_map` doesn't use `operator <`, instead it relies on a specialization of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) which `pair` doesn't provide. You'll have to provide one yourself or, preferably, switch to a `struct` with a `std::hash` specialization instead of using `pair` .

Comment: Would you please post a full comment and a complete minimal testable solution to my problem? I will vote it up and choose the good answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Comment: or just use boost::unordered_map which automatically hashes std::pair (I wish the STL had adopted that feature...)

Comment: Thank you but could you tell me why it is not good to use my data type in std ? My type is defined in my own program anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As @Bo Persson and @Sean Cline mentioned in the comments, you will need to use a custom  hash function/functor to do that.

[LIVE DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/w0gpEJ)

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct  {  int x, y;  };
using Key = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

namespace something 
{
    struct Compare      //custom hash function/functor
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Key& string_pair) const
        {
            // just to demonstrate the comparison.
            return std::hash<std::string>{}(string_pair.first) ^
                    std::hash<std::string>{}(string_pair.second);
        }
    };
}
using myMap = std::unordered_map<Key, myStruct, something::Compare>;

int main()
{
    myMap mp =
    {
        { { "name1", "name2" },{ 3,4 } },
        { { "aame1", "name2" },{ 8,4 } },
        { std::make_pair("fame1", "name2"),{ 2,4 } }, // or make pair
        { std::make_pair("fame1", "bame2"),{ 1,2 } }
    };

    for(const auto& it: mp)
    {
        std::cout << it.first.first << " " << it.first.second << " "
                 << it.second.x << " " << it.second.y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, every symmetric pair will make almost same hashes and that can cause, 
 hash collisions and thereby less performance. Nevertheless, additional specializations for `std::pair` to compose hashes are available in [boost.hash](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html)

---

An alternative solution, could be using `std::map<>`. There you can also specify the custom function/functor for the `std::pair`, in order to achieve the same map structure. Even though there you will not have to face hash-collisions, that would be well sorted which you might not want.

[LIVE DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/fTbIcX)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct {  int x, y; };
using Key =  std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

namespace something
{
    struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const
        {
            // do the required comparison here
            return std::tie(lhs.first, lhs.second) < std::tie(rhs.first, rhs.second);
        }
    };
}
using myMap = std::map<Key, myStruct, something::Compare>;
```

---

> could you tell me why it is not good to use my data type in std ? My
>   type is defined in my own program anyway.

You shouldn't make it under the namespace of `std`, because it can cause a UB. A well defined situations/exceptions  where you can extend `std` namespace are given here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the secondary question:

> Thank you but could you tell me why it is not good to use my data type in std ? My type is defined in my own program anyway

You feel that you can define whatever you want in your program, right? (That is the impression you gave, at least.) Well, C++ implementations feel the same way about `namespace std` -- it is their namespace and they can define whatever they want in it (subject to the C++ standard, of course).

If an implementation needs to define a (possibly undocumented) helper function/class/whatever, the expectation is that it can be placed in `namespace std` without conflicting with your program. Case in point: what would happen to your program if your C++ library decided that it needed to define a specialization of the `std::pair` template for `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`? To my knowledge, the standard neither requires nor prohibits such a specialization, so the existence of it is left to the implementor's discretion.

Namespaces exist to prevent naming conflicts. In particular, `namespace std` exists to isolate C++ implementation details from user programs. Adding your code to `namespace std` destroys that isolation, hence the standard declares it undefined behavior. Don't do it.

*(That being said, there is nothing stopping you from writing a wrapper class around `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` to get the functionality you need. Just do it in your own namespace.)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a specialization of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for your key type, like so:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>


using KeyType = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<KeyType>
    {
        size_t operator()(KeyType const& kt) const
        {
            size_t hash = 0;
            hash_combine(hash, kt.first);
            hash_combine(hash, kt.second);
            return hash;
        }
        // taken from boost::hash_combine:
        // https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine
        template <class T>
        inline static void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
        {
            std::hash<T> hasher;
            seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<KeyType, int> us;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to specialize `std::hash` for template arguments that are not dependent on any user type