# What is the best way to get a permutation index list of a given vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

In my application I solve a geometric problem on a given list of points.

```
0 x0 y0
1 x1 y1
...
```

The solution file should contain a specific ordering of the points which are represented as a list of their indexes.

```
1
0
...
```

After solving the problem I have a `result = std::vector<Point>()` vector of point objects in a certain order as well as the original list of points as an `original = std::vector<Point>()` vector. Both vectors naturally have the same size. To generate the output file I go through the `result` vector and search for the index of the point in the `original` vector. This is quite inefficient because it does need `O(n^2)` time. As a slight improvement I do the following:

```
std::ofstream out(filename);

std::vector<int> indices(instance.size);
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

for(auto &point : instance.result.points)
{
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<indices.size(); i++)
    {
        int id = indices[i];
        if(point == instance.points[id])
        {
            out << id << std::endl;
            indices.erase(indices.begin()+i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

out.close();
```

This allows me to not revisit the points that I already found before. Sadly for a 1 million point instance, this process exceeds my time limit and I don't want the export of my solution to take more time than solving the problem itself. Is there a way to efficiently get the indexes of a premutation of some vector in C++? The solution can use a lot of memory if desired.

Comment: When solving the problem work with vector of indexes already, then you do not need to scan again.

Comment: Sadly this is not possible because I am using an external library which only accepts a given list of points.

Comment: Then fill `std::unordered_map<Point,size_t>` and do lookup there.

Comment: Sadly the point object is not hashable.

Comment: Why it is not hashable? If that is the point (which I hardly doubt), use `std::map` instead. Don't say they are not comparable

Comment: @Slava I get a static_assert failed due to requirement __check_hash_requirements. I know I can somehow provide my ohn hash function and I will try that if there is no better solution

Comment: @Riddick I don't quite understand how to obtain the right indices, can you be more precise?

Comment: Is your input list sorted?

Comment: "and I will try that if there is no better solution" that's already a better and pretty simple solution.

Comment: Is it possible at all to know how the indices are transformed? Does your algorithm force you to lose all information about how the points are permuted, because if I understand correctly, you can carry a list of indices through the algorithm, then sort the original list based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simple to implement and quite efficient solution is to create a temporary `std::unordered_map<Point,size_t>` where key is the point and value is position inside `original`, then do lookup in that map. Details on how to use your (or library provided) data type as a key in `std::unordered_map` provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/432358)

Comment: Yes, it does work indeed with an `std::map` as well as with an `std::unordered_map` when I implement the hash function myself. Both options fulfill my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `Point` structure to contain the original id, besides the position.

Comment: For my specific task I dont have control over the point structure, because it is provided by an external library.

Comment: But when I pass my custom structure to the external library it will automatically cut off the additional `size_t` or am I mistaken?

Comment: Not necessarily. Can you share more details about the library you use/methods you call, if it's open source? Also, what is the Point type and what does it contain? It might be possible to extend it to add the index.

Comment: I'm using CGAL to perform some geometric operations. Therefore I'm using `Kernel::Point_2` for some (user-defined) kernel. The `std::map` solution does work good enough for me. Thank you anyways!