# How to make std::unorder_set of custom string like type?

Tags: c++, hash, c++17, unordered-map

Suppose I have a custom string like type:

```
struct MyType {
  std::string str_;
  int somethingElse;
}
```

Now, I know how to make it usuable in a std::set - just supply `<` operator.

**How can I use it with a `std::unordered_set` ?** when it is supposed to be based on the `std::string str_` member ?

```
std::unordered_set<MyType> um;
```

**Update:** I have already seen this answer: [C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)
It looks somewhat outdated(c++11 ?) and also concerns `map`

Comment: Any reason why you want to use `std::unordered_set<MyType>` instead of `std:unordered_map<std::string, int>` ?

Comment: The answer is exactly the same for `std::unordered_set`. And it didn't change between C++11 and C++17.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen hmmm, really, i have to specialize within the std namespace ?

Comment: Adding template specializations for `std::hash` is the only (known to me) exception in standard, when you are allowed to add something to `namespace std`. But you can provide your hash functor as template argument for `std::unordered_set` as well, which is nicer IMO. And given that your hash function will be just returning hash of `std::string`, I'd rather go for `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen normally a good idea, but I simply can't make the map work with actual code.

Comment: You have to either provide a `std::hash<MyType>` or use `std::unordered_set<MyType, MyHasher>` as the type where `MyHasher` acts like `std::hash<MyType>` would.