# std::unordered_map<std::string, myCustomClass> what operators to overload and how?

Tags: c++

I want to use a custom class of mine as the value of a std::unordered_map

such as

```
class customClass {
    private:
        int m_age;
        std::string m_name;
    public:
        int getAge() { return m_age; }
        std::string getName() { return m_name; }
};
...
std::unordered_map<std::string, customClass> entries;
```

I know for this to work and me be able to insert key / value pairs I have to overload some operators but do I overload the == operator for std::string? something else? Bit lost, cheers for any help

Comment: You want your class as the **value** or the **key** of this `unordered_map`?  You don't need to do anything to use it as the _value_.

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  The requirements only apply to the key type and the standard library already has everything needed for `std::string`.  For a duplicate for what you need for your own type, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Answer (score 1):

> std::unordered_map<std::string, myCustomClass> what operators to overload and how?

You don't need to implement any particular operators.  The type just needs to be constructible, *somehow*.

[Your class already is sufficient for the job.](https://godbolt.org/z/PE4jKW)