# How to write a custom hash_function for std::unordered_map<T> in cpp?

Tags: c++, std

I want to write my own Hash_function for an std::unordered_map instead of using the default one.
I could find unordered_map::hash_function() on many websites.
But using this i can only get the Hash value generated, using something like this :

```
/*Sample map of strings*/

unordered_map<string, string> sample;

// inserts key and elements
sample.insert({ "Tom", "MNNIT" });
sample.insert({ "Kate", "MNNIT" });

unordered_map<string, string>::hasher foo
    = sample.hash_function();

cout << foo("Tom") << endl;
```

But how can i have more control and create my own version of the hashing function ? So, that for example lets say for the key "Tom", i want hash value to be 100.

Comment: Use a good source code editor like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: Read wikipedia about [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), the [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), and explain in several paragraphs of written English why do you require that the hashcode of `"Tom"` should be 100. Provide some [mre] in your question. What will happen to you if the hashcode of `"Tom"` is *not* 100? Read also [documentation of `std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/9676206

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` is templated off of a `Hasher` that defaults to `std::hash<Key>`. You can change your variable to `std::unordered_map<string, string, CustomHasher>`. `unordered_map` will then default construct a `CustomHasher` (it can also be passed in the constructor if you can't default construct your hashing object).

A custom hasher needs to provide a call operator such as the following:

```
struct CustomHasher
{
    // noexcept is recommended, but not required
    std::size_t operator()(const std::string& s) const /*noexcept*/
    {
        return /*hash computation here*/;
    }
};
```

Note: Writing code that depends on the hash values of something stored in an `unordered_map` is typically a bad design. There are valid use cases for wanting a custom hash function such as when you can exploit some information specific to your data to generate better hashes, but those cases are quite rare.

Comment: Just a note: it doesn't have to be `noexcept`.

Comment: @Evg good point, removed it from the example.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask to remove `noexcept`. Having a `noexcept` hasher is a good thing but the standard doesn't mandate non-throwing custom hashers. For example, libstdc++ does some internal optimization for `noexcept` hashers (it a hasher is not `noexcept` then a hash code has to be stored in a node, see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable.h#L44). In that particular implementation `noexcept` alone is not enough to trigger optimization (hasher should also be "fast"), but in some other implementation it might be important.