# Multiple std::hash specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, std, stdhash

I have a class

```
class Base {
...
virtual size_t GetHash() = 0;
...
};
```

and a number of classes, inherited from `Base`, that override `GetHash()`.

I want to use these classes as a key in `unordered_map` or `unordered_set`. Currently I achieve it by using

```
struct HashKey
{
    template <typename T>
    size_t operator()(const T & obj) const
    {
        return obj.GetHash();
    }
};
```

as a `Hash` class in `unordered_map` template (like `unordered_map<MyDerived, int, Hashkey>`).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key), I can explicitly specialize `std::hash<T>` for my own class and totally works fine, but I'm interested if there any way to specialize it for multiple classes?

I'm using C++17

Comment: you mean one specialization that works for all your classes that have a `GetHash` method? The question is not quite clear. If you know how to specialize for one you can also specialize for many, but I suppose you are looking for some shortcut

Comment: A little nitpicking here: The classes that derive from `Base` ***override*** the `GetHash` function from the base class, not overload. If they were overloaded, then they would use different arguments.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely looking for some shortcut, cause there're a lot of classes.

Comment: Since your type is polymorphic, You could have all of your containers store a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` as the element type, and then you would just need to specialize `std::hash` for `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Make it work for all T where T [has a base class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) of `Base`.
Without `requires`, this is done using SFINAE and `enable_if`.

Comment: Could you show how you would do this?  `std::hash` only has a single template parameter so I'm not certain how you would do the specialization.

Comment: I'm afraid it only leads to an error ```error: default template argument in a class template partial specialization```