# Using A Struct As Key For std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to use a struct as a key for an `unordered_map`. I added the 'spaceship' operator to the structure, which solved errors I was getting with normal comparisons, such as "is struct 1 greater than struct 2?", etc. However, I am getting `attempting to reference a deleted function` when using it as a key for my map. From what understood, adding the spaceship operator should have allowed me to use the struct as the map key. What is wrong?

```
struct test
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;

    auto operator<=>(const test&) const = default;
};

std::unordered_map<test, uint32_t> x; // Causes error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a structure as a key in an unordered_map, you need two things:

- A "hasher", something that will take a `const test &` and compute a hash, which defaults to `std:hash<test>`, and
- A comparison predicate, which defaults to `std::equal_to<test>`.

You've got the second one covered with your spaceship operator, but not the first.  There is no `std::hash<test>`.

See [C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key) for an example as how to define your own hasher.

Comment: Don't you think this question is a duplicate of the one linked in your answer?

Comment: Yes, mostly.  But not the bit about the comparator. (especially using `<=>`)