# How to insert an element of vector2 and int to a hash table?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I am trying to make a hash table that takes on a `Vector2` as its key and an int as its value, but when I try to insert a key and value pair in its insert function I get an error:

```
no matching function for call to std::pair<Vector2, int>::pair(const Vector2&, int).
```

If anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it, please help.

```
void HashTable::insert(const Vector2& key, int value)
{
    int index = hashFunction(key) % m_buckets.size();
    m_buckets.insert(m_buckets.begin() + index, std::make_pair(key, value));
}
```

I tried to use a different way to insert that is:

```
m_buckets[index].push_back(make_pair(key, value)
```

but it only gives me another error:

```
struct std::pair<Vector2, int> has no member named push.back
```

`Vector2` is a vector class that takes to integers x and y.

```
std::vector<std::pair<Vector2, int>> m_buckets
```

Comment: what is `Vector2` ? You are using some library. Which one is it?

Comment: Why not use `std::map<Vector2,int>`, and provide an overloaded std::hash<Vector2> function? Also see : [custom hash for unordered map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

Comment: `m_buckets[index].first.push_back(stuff)`

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `Vector2` class does not provide a copy constructor. Without it, I got the very same error message.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ca7r96roe

As for the second problem, you are trying to `push_back` into a vector element, which type is `std::pair`. `std::pair` does not have a `push_back` member function. Maybe, you wanted something as:

```
m_buckets[index] = std::make_pair(key, value);
```