How to use std::unordered_map with different enum- type state classes
I'm creating a class which represents sprite sheets in C++. This is essentially an image file with varying number of rows and columns. Each row represents a game character doing one thing, e.g. first row is player walking left, second row is playing walking right etc. Similarly for different character the first row can be shark moving up etc.
To represent these states, I plan to create enum class, e.g. for game character the states are
   enum class HeroState {
       Idle,
       MovingLeft,
       MovingRight,
   };

For other characters these states are obviously different (SharkState, BombState).
Now I would like to create a SpriteSheet class, which I could parametrize so that given row in sprite sheet is associated with State and columns. For example (syntax not right in this),
heroSpriteSheet->setSpriteSheetData({{HeroState.Idle, 0, 19}, {HeroState.MovingLeft, 1, 14}});
sharkSpriteSheet->setSpriteSheetData({{SharkState.SwimLeft, 0, 12}, {SharkState.SwimRight, 1, 12}}); 

Then in code, when I know what the state is, I can query the SpriteSheet class for row and column information by giving just the state.
I consider using the std::unordered_map<State, RowAndColumnInfo> but how I can use it with the different State classes? I have HeroState, VillainState... etc. Should I use templates or is there some better way?
At the moment I'm still in planning phase.

Do hero's and villain's really need different states?  Can't you just have a sprite state enum that has enumerations for all of the actions your sprites can do?

You could make the other state classes inherit from State, but you need a comparison operator and other stuff to make it work as a key in the unordered_map. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

@SvenNilsson Enum's have no base classes (they only have underlying types, which are required to be integral primitive types)

You probably don't need to. Since heroSpriteSheet and sharkSpriteSheet are separate objects, they can be templated on the enum:
Live On Coliru
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct RowAndColumnInfo {
    int row, column; 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, RowAndColumnInfo const& r) {
        return os << "(" << r.row << "," << r.column << ")";
    }
};

template <typename State>
class SpriteSheet {
  public:
    SpriteSheet(std::initializer_list<std::pair<State const, RowAndColumnInfo>> data = {}) : m_data(data) {}

    void setSpriteSheetData(std::initializer_list<std::pair<State const, RowAndColumnInfo>> data) {
        m_data.insert(data);
    }

    RowAndColumnInfo getRowAndColumnInfo(State state) const { return m_data.at(state); }

  private:
    std::unordered_map<State, RowAndColumnInfo> m_data;
};

enum class HeroState { Idle, MovingLeft, MovingRight };
enum class SharkState { SwimLeft, SwimRight };

int main() {
    SpriteSheet<HeroState> heroSpriteSheet({{HeroState::Idle, {0, 19}}, {HeroState::MovingLeft, {1, 14}}});
    SpriteSheet<SharkState> sharkSpriteSheet({{SharkState::SwimLeft, {0, 12}}, {SharkState::SwimRight, {1, 12}}});

    std::cout << heroSpriteSheet.getRowAndColumnInfo(HeroState::Idle) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sharkSpriteSheet.getRowAndColumnInfo(SharkState::SwimRight) << std::endl;
}

Printing
(0,19)    
(1,12)

BONUS
If you prefer the type to be identical, you can template the insertion/extraction methods instead, and have them do the conversions:
Live On Coliru
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

struct RowAndColumnInfo {
    int row, column; 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, RowAndColumnInfo const& r) {
        return os << "(" << r.row << "," << r.column << ")";
    }
};

class SpriteSheet {
  public:
    using Underlying = int;

    template <typename Enum>
    void setSpriteSheetData(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Enum const, RowAndColumnInfo>> data) {
        for (auto& p : data) {
            m_data[std::to_underlying(p.first)] = p.second;
            // m_data[static_cast<State>(p.first)] = p.second;
        }
    }

    template <typename Enum> RowAndColumnInfo getRowAndColumnInfo(Enum state) const {
        return m_data.at(std::to_underlying(state));
        // return m_data.at(static_cast<State>(state));
    }

  private:
    std::unordered_map<Underlying, RowAndColumnInfo> m_data;
};

enum class HeroState : SpriteSheet::Underlying { Idle, MovingLeft, MovingRight };
enum class SharkState : SpriteSheet::Underlying { SwimLeft, SwimRight };

int main() {
    SpriteSheet heroSpriteSheet, sharkSpriteSheet;
    heroSpriteSheet.setSpriteSheetData<HeroState>(
        {{HeroState::Idle, {0, 19}}, {HeroState::MovingLeft, {1, 14}}});
    sharkSpriteSheet.setSpriteSheetData<SharkState>(
        {{SharkState::SwimLeft, {0, 12}}, {SharkState::SwimRight, {1, 12}}});

    std::cout << heroSpriteSheet.getRowAndColumnInfo(HeroState::Idle) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sharkSpriteSheet.getRowAndColumnInfo(SharkState::SwimRight) << std::endl;
}

Printing the same.

Added a bonus take doing explicit conversions instead, using c++23 std::to_underlying when possible

using Underlying as the key will cause any Idle Hero to be replaced with a SwimLeft Sprite, not sure if that is intended

you can fix that by something along the line of  SwimLeft = MovingRight +1

@463035818_is_not_an_ai they're still separate maps! But I recommend the first approach for having the type safety.

Oh now I get it. Misread the code
